# DeSerialize list of objects using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I have a JSON string that is deserialized into an object of type RList. However, inside the RList, there is an array of objects of types like RInteger, RDouble, etc. All of these types implements the interface RDatatype. When deserializing this list, its deserializes the JSON to RList but not the objects inside the list. It takes those objects as Maps. Here's the code the deserializes:

```
public RDatatype deserialize(String json) throws JsonParseException,
        JsonMappingException, IOException {
    RDatatype obj =  mapper.readValue(json, RList.class);

    return obj;
}
```

And here's the test case that fails:

```
public void testDeSerialize() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    RDatatype obj = new RList();
    RList test = new RList();
    obj = test.deserialize("{\"value\":[{\"value\":5,\"type\":\"Integer\"},{\"value\":6.4,\"type\":\"Double\"}],\"type\":\"List\"}");

    List<RDatatype> l = (List<RDatatype>) obj.getValue();
    for (int i=0; i<l.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(l.get(i));
    }
    assertTrue(true);
}
```

Please let me know if you require more information. Thanks.

Comment: Does RList extends List<RDataType>? In either case take a look at [this](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQ#Deserializing_Generic_types)  page to understand how to deal with generic collectons.

Comment: You need to include definition of `RList`, to know what the actual problem is.

Comment: Yes RList extends RDatatype.

Comment: RDatatype or List<RDatatype>? Please include definition of RList.

Comment: Could you post the definition of RList and at least one of the other datatypes (e.g. RInteger)?